# Does visual basic use static/lexical or dynamic scoping?

Tags: dynamic, static, vb6, scope, scoping

could anyone tell me if Visual Basic uses dynamic scoping or lexical scoping?
Think it's static scoping but not sure!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vb6 uses static scoping. It resolves scope in the following order:

- Local symbols
- Module symbols
- Global symbols
- Type library references

Comment: +1 Also type library references are resolved in the order in which they are listed on the references dialogue box. [This VB6 help topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231205(v=vs.60).aspx) explains variable scope (although not type library references)